# Infinite loop causes OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java

I'm writing a chat application. I use a `while(true)` infinite loop to allow the application to constantly "listen" to both user input through the console and input from a `Socket`. The infinite loop clearly isn't the optimal way to accomplish this - not surprisingly, I get an `OutOfMemoryError: Java Heap space` after only about a minute of the program running (and my computer's fans screaming).

My question is: if not through an infinite loop, how can I modify my program to constantly (or at least at small intervals, like once every second) check the input sources, respond, and then go back to checking?

The code (with some notes) is below:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ConnectException {
        ServerSocket receiveServerSocket = new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(args[0])); // args contains two port numbers
        Socket sendSocket;
        while(true) { // note - I use the exact same infinite loop strategy here, except in this case an OutOfMemoryError is not thrown
            try {
                sendSocket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
                break;
            } catch (ConnectException e) {}
        }
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(sendSocket.getOutputStream());
        Socket receiveSocket = receiveServerSocket.accept();
        DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(receiveSocket.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String message;
        while(true) { // Here's the infinite loop in question
            if(input.ready()) { // "checks" to see if the user has entered text
                message = input.readLine(); // responds
                os.writeInt(message.getBytes().length);     
                os.writeBytes(message);
            }
            if(is.available() > 0) { // checks to see if Socket has received text
                byte[] bytes = new byte[is.readInt()]; // responds (Incidentally, this is the specific line where the OutOfMemoryError occurs)
                is.read(bytes,0,bytes.length);
                System.out.println(new String(bytes,0,bytes.length,"UTF-8"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: why not move the `byte[]` variable instantiation outside of the loop, the JVM should optimize it out, but it's bad practice anyways.

Comment: Make sense, I'll do that and see how much difference it makes

Comment: On the line that is crashing: byte[] bytes = new byte[is.readInt()]  .... how big is the size that you are trying to allocate ?

Comment: Not sure, do you mean the length of the `byte[]`?

Comment: Your problem is probably that `writeBytes` is occasionally starting with a handful of numeric characters.  Then when `readInt` occurs, it's getting more than just the integer that was written - it's reading some extra digits for the end.  Then the amount of memory allocated ends up being a whole lot more than it should be.

Comment: That must be it - how would I fix this?

Comment: This is some spaghetti code!  -- why not do something like `while(!input.ready()) { /* your stuff */ }`

Comment: also, never throw exceptions from `main()` as this will terminate your JVM and not display the stack trace properly or at all. its a bad bad practice to suppress exceptions as well, you should either print them to the console, log them, or handle them in some fashion, unless there is a very good reason to not ever need to know that an error occurred during program execution.

Comment: Not sure how doing `while(!input.ready()` would help, since I need it to do stuff if `input.ready()` is true, and otherwise just continuously repeat. The `ConnectException` is expected so doesn't need to be handled, although the IOException could be.

Comment: @asaini007 - If my suspicion is correct about `writeBytes`, then I would suggest writing an extra separator, such as a space or a comma, between the `writeInt` and the `writeBytes`, and of course reading it too.  Of course, I'm not certain that this is your problem, which is why I posted a comment, not an answer.

Comment: `readInt()` seems to correctly know how many bytes the message is, but for some reason `is.read` doesn't read the entire message. Then, when the *next* message is sent, the byte[]'s length is garbage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems.

(1) You need to change

```
os.writeBytes(message);
```

to

```
os.write(message.getBytes(), 0, message.getBytes().length);
```

The reason is that `writeBytes` discards one byte from every `String`.  From the Javadoc -

> Writes out the string to the underlying output stream as a sequence of
>   bytes. Each character in the string is written out, in sequence, by
>   discarding its high eight bits. If no exception is thrown, the counter
>   written is incremented by the length of s.

The effect of this of course is that the number of bytes you've written is actually half of the number of bytes you specified when you called `writeInt`.

(2) You should write some kind of separator character such as a space after the call to `writeInt`, in case the byte sequence begins with numeric characters.  Otherwise, the call to `readInt` might read the wrong number from the stream.

Comment: What does `discarding its high eight bits` even mean?

Comment: (1) works, (2) might be a good idea, probably not necessary I think because writeInt() will always precede the actual message with an int

Comment: A Java `char` is always 16 bits.  So a `String` takes twice as many bytes as its length.  `writeBytes` only writes every second byte.

Answer (score 1):

Try printing the value of `is.readInt()`. It might be possible that you are reading a garbage value and trying to allocate that much memory resulting in the OutOfMemoryError. 
Also put the while loop in a thread and call `Thread.sleep(1000)` to make the checking periodic with a 1 sec interval.

Comment: I think this is the problem - not reading the correct length and getting a garbage value - how would I fix that? I'll look into threads, never used them before.

Comment: If you are writing the program that sends the data as well then set a maximum length at both server and client, create a byte[] of that much length that you should reuse at the client end avoiding 'new' everytime. That should solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Some of my observations :

- Your first loop is not infinite loop.
- You might want to sleep in between reads using
  Thread.slpee(1000)
- Release byte array after you are done with it.
  bytes = null; // last statement in your second if check

Comment: The first loop is an infinite loop until the connection is made, and if I leave it disconnected it runs forever. I'll look into the second two though

Answer (score 0):

Your first while loop isn't really a loop as it breaks right after assigning a value to sendsocket.

Maybe have a flag for your application like

```
bool isRunning=true;
```

and you can do,

```
while(isRunning)
```

and when your application is closed it'll change isRunning=false, & kick out of the loop.

Comment: I'm talking about the second while loop - the first while loop is meant to close as is does